# Is binary search as efficient as it normally is?

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary-search

If array inherits from object, is binary searching still useful/quick?

Comment: What does Array inheriting from Object have to do with anything?

Comment: What? Huh? Congratulations, I'm now as confused as you must be.

Comment: All that matters is what kind of random-access guarantees are offered by Array.  Which, hopefully, are... you know, array like.

Comment: @Michael: Sorry, it's probably a silly question but with all of javascripts strange flaws and quirks it had me worried that arrays were actually just objects in disguise or something!

Comment: there's nothing inherently wrong with objects wrt performance. I think it's generally safe to assume that an Array will have a performance profile of N(1) access, which is what you need for binary searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reason why it wouldn't be. It only inherits from object so that you can treat it like an object, I doubt it is implemented in a way that would make binary search somehow inefficient.

Comment: Do people really use db that big to even make a difference? And if they do shouldn't it be server side?